# Remove (or substitute) a word with slashes with sed

Tags: sed

I made a script that uses du at some point, to show the space used into a directory. I want that to to be showed without the "/home/azarilh" in the string. I was trying to remove that with an example...

What i have:

```
5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd
```

What i want to get:

```
5G /folder/asd
```

I have tried (using echo instead of du as an example):

```
echo "5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd" | sed -e 's/\<\/home\/azarilh\>//g'
```

Would be better to get "~/folder/asd" instead of just removing "/home/azarilh".
Doesn't need to be sed, i have tried with grep but with no success. I use grep to remove prefixes and it works.

```
echo "$string" | grep -oP "^$prefix\K.*"
```

Maybe it can be modified to work in this case?

Comment: `\<` matches start of word, but `/` is not a word character, so `\<\/` will never match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
echo "5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd" | sed -e 's+/home/azarilh+~+g'
# output: 5G ~/folder/asd
```

When you use `sed` you specify the pattern, what to change like `s/from/to/g` (to change "from" to "to"), but the `/` delimiter can be almost anything. So if you have `/` slashes in the string you want to modify, you can use something other than `/`, for example `+` as above.

You could also use on any output `sed -e "s+${HOME}+~+` to replace your `${HOME}` directory with `~`.

But I think I should also mention, you can get a similar output to what you want by running `du -hs ./*` in your `${HOME}` directory.

Comment: All three answers work, but using another character instead of the slash really is useful and simple to understand, hence, best answer. Thank you. Your du solution, tho', leaves a dot at the beginning of the directory, surely better than full path but substituting it with whatever i want is better.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following.

```
cho "5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd" | sed 's/\([^ ]* \)\/[^/]*\/[^/]*\(.*\)/\1\2/'
```

***Detailed explanation:*** Using `sed`'s group referencing capability here, which allows us to save matched regex into buffer memory with identification of `1`,`2` etc and so on. So when a regex is mentioned in between `\(....\)` and a match found in line then it will be saved into memory with reference of digit(which will depend upon its matched number, eg--> 1st matched regex reference number will be `\1`).

---

***2nd solution:*** If you are ok with an `awk` solution it will be pretty simple(considering that you always have to print in output in same fashion).

```
echo "5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd" | awk -F'[ /]' '{print $1 OFS "/"$(NF-1)"/"$NF}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

Remove the /home/azarilh part and replace it with ~.

I think that's what you desire, right?

```
$ echo "5G /home/azarilh/folder/asd" | sed -e 's/\/home\/azarilh/~/g'
5G ~/folder/asd
```